# Custom jboss-app.xml using Maven

Tags: maven, jboss, maven-ear-plugin

I declared a custom `jboss-app.xml` in my `pom.xml`, but the plugin is generating an internal and empty `jboss-app.xml` file into `ear/META-INF`.

I created my `pom.xml` based on this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2008/jw-06-build-the-enterprise.html?page=1) with the following definition:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <data-sources>
            <data-source>${artifactId}/src/main/resources/mytest-ds.xml</data-source>
        </data-sources>
        <jboss>${artifactId}/src/main/resources/jboss-app.xml</jboss>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.testproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb-project</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But, I can't handle my custom `jboss-app.xml`. A new is empty descriptor (without defined ejbs) is generated every time.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply include your `jboss-app.xml` in your source tree and Maven will pull it in.

Your project directory structure for the maven-ear-plugin should look like:

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- application
            `-- META-INF
                |-- application.xml
                `-- jboss-app.xml
```

Then just run `mvn package` to create your EAR.  Assuming the packaging for your pom.xml is 'ear' it will pull jboss-app.xml into your resulting ear.

Also, I believe your `<datasources>...</datasources>` configuration needs to be within the `<jboss>...</jboss>` tags.

See also: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Deployment-of-the-jboss-app-xml-file-td45009.html

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, it looks like [jboss](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/generating-jboss-app.html) tag triggers the generation of `jboss-app.xml`.  How about omitting this tag and generating the `ear`?

Comment: I already omitted this tag, but maven doesn't take my src/main/{resources,java}/jboss-app.xml file from any path. I tried declaring the descriptor inside po.xml and its worked. But, I don't like to put this information inside maven descriptor because I'm creating an undesirable dependency with mvn. I'm looking for a solution for this. Any news, I post here.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative would be to pull datasources via `application.xml` as described [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-ear-problem-Jboss-can-t-find-datasource-file-td97374.html). But as `<jarModule>` requires are full-blown maven artifact, that is longer way (perhaps for application servers other than JBoss):

• `project/ds/pom.xml`:

```
<artifactId>project-ds</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>My DataSource</name>
```

• `project/ds/src/main/resources/my-ds.xml`:

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
    ...
```

• `project/ear/pom.xml` (assuming that driver is also packaged in EAR):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-ds</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-war</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>${jtds.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <modules>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
                <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
                <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
            </jarModule>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>project-ds</artifactId>
                <unpack>true</unpack>
                <uri>/</uri>
                <bundleFileName>my-ds.xml</bundleFileName>
                <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
            </jarModule>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>project-war</artifactId>
                <contextRoot>${context.path}</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Will generate `META-INF/application.xml`:

```
<application>
  <display-name>project-ear</display-name>
  <description>...</description>
  <module>
    <java>jtds-1.2.4.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>my-ds.xml</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>project-war-1.0.0.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```